# Select column for formatting based on cell content

Tags: xlsxwriter

In xlsxWriter I can format a column by selecting its column index as it is in Excel via letters e.g. `worksheet.set_column('V:V', 20, cell_format)`. Is it also possible to define which column to format based on its value (e.g. header columns)?

For example `worksheet.set_column('cell_value', 20, cell_format)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it also possible to define which column to format based on its value (e.g. header columns)?

That isn't possible using xlsxwriter, which in general is a write-only data store. Instead you could track the column headers and indices in a dict and use that. Something like

```py
cols = {'Year' : 0, 'Income': 1, 'Outgoings': 2}


worksheet.set_column(cols['Year'], cols['Year'], 20, cell_format)
```

Comment: Great, thank you (great package btw)!